# How to groupby a dynamic condition on a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the `nested_list`... This nested list is based on another grouping

```py
nested_list = [[[0, 59.87271881103516]],
 [[1, 56.33743667602539], [2, 12.141159057617188]],
 [[3, 116.6510009765625]],
 [[4, 98.58261108398438], [5, 98.01058959960938]],
 [[5, 98.01058959960938], [6, -2.2177391052246094]],
 [[7, -7.6250953674316415], [8, 89.80469512939453]],
 [[8, 89.80469512939453],
  [9, 14.612628936767578],
  [10, 10.861335754394531],
  [11, 33.497543334960945],
  [12, 114.00135040283205],
  [13, 29.74617004394531],
  [14, 45.50025939941406],
  [15, 12.267791748046877],
  [16, 107.34764862060548],
  [17, 25.24243927001953]],
 [[18, 1.3098258972167969],
  [19, -6.511528015136719],
  [20, -8.737972259521483]],
 [[20, -8.737972259521483],
  [21, -1.0142173767089844],
  [22, 109.0613784790039]],
 [[21, -1.0142173767089844],
  [22, 109.0613784790039],
  [23, -7.488857269287108],
  [24, -11.845829010009766],
  [25, 108.14006042480467],
  [26, -0.218780517578125],
  [27, -15.114391326904297]],
 [[23, -7.488857269287108],
  [24, -11.845829010009766],
  [25, 108.14006042480467],
  [26, -0.218780517578125],
  [27, -15.114391326904297],
  [28, -11.57907485961914],
  [29, 46.48944091796875],
  [30, -11.690120697021484]]
    ]
```

...  I want a function that returns the following `expected_output`:

```py
expected_output = [
[[0],
 [1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4, 5],
 [6],
 [7],
 [8]
 [9, 10, 15],
 [11, 13, 17],
 [12, 16],
 [14],
 [18, 19],
 [19, 20],
 [20, 21],
 [21, 23, 26],
 [22, 25],
 [23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30],
[29]]
]
```

I can not have sublist in the nested list so if I can only have [[5,6],[6,7]] but not [[5,6],[5],[6,7]] since the [5] is a sublist of [5,6].

I want to group the `nested_list` in a +/- 10 unit.

My attempt:

```py
import numpy as np

def my_attempt(nested_list: list) -> list:
    group = []
    for k in range(len(nested_list)):
        df_irt = np.array([el[1] for el in nested_list[k]])
        df_irt_index = np.array([el[0] for el in nested_list[k]])
        data3 = df_irt - 10
        data4 = df_irt + 10

        for i in range(len(df_irt)):
            s_i = []
            for j in range(i, len(df_irt)):
                if data3[i] < df_irt[j] < data4[i]:
                    s_i.append(df_irt_index[j])
            group.append(s_i)
    return group
group =my_attempt(nested_list)
fset = set(frozenset(x) for x in group)
group = sorted([list(x) for x in fset], key=lambda x: x[0])
d = {}
for i, l in enumerate(group):
    for v in l:
        d.setdefault(v, set()).add(i)

group = [l for i, l in enumerate(group) if not set.intersection(*(d[x] for x in l)).difference({i})]
group
```

The problem is that large nested list results in RAM error; therefore I need a more optimized solution.

Comment: How `[4,5]` is coming in the output ,Can you explain

Comment: cuz 4  (+-10 unit) is  [88.58261108398438 ,108.58261108398438 ] and 5 have   98.01058959960938 which is inside the interval

Comment: 5 and 8 are present twice, why is that?

Comment: [[4, 98.58261108398438], [5, 98.01058959960938]],
    [[5, 98.01058959960938], [6, -2.2177391052246094]], we find 5 twice because of the previous grouping so 4 and 5 share the same window and also 5 and 6 share the same window but 4 and 6 do not so they are separated

Answer (score 1):

This gives me a slighly different result than what you expect. However, this is what seems to be correct according to how I interpret your description of the problem.

```py
import math


def group_nested_list(nested_list: list, diff: int = 10) -> list:
    result = []
    for lists in nested_list:
        lists = sorted(lists, key=lambda x: x[1])

        curr = -math.inf
        sub_result = []
        for list_ in lists:
            if list_[1] - curr > diff:
                if len(sub_result) > 0:
                    result.append(sub_result)
                sub_result = [list_[0]]
                curr = list_[1]
            else:
                if len(sub_result) > 0:
                    sub_result.append(list_[0])
                else:
                    result[-1].append(list_[0])
                    curr = list_[1]

        result.append(sub_result)

    result = sorted([sorted(x) for x in result], key=lambda x: x[0])

    return remove_sublists(result)
```

```py
def remove_sublists(result: list) -> list:
    mask = [True] * len(result)
    for i, lst_i in enumerate(result):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(result)):
            if set(lst_i).issubset(set(result[j])):
                mask[i] = False
            elif set(result[j]).issubset(set(lst_i)):
                mask[j] = False

    return [x for x, m in zip(result, mask) if m]
```

Output:

```py
[[0],
 [1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4, 5],
 [6],
 [7],
 [8],
 [9, 10, 15],
 [11, 13, 17],
 [12, 16],
 [14],
 [18],
 [19, 20],
 [20, 21],
 [21, 26],
 [22, 25],
 [23, 24, 27, 28, 30],
 [29]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code, the only thing is I cannot have sublist in the nested list so [4,5] [5], I only can have [4,5] and only 1 of [8]

Comment: for example when I made the list bigger this code gives me [[0],
 [1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4, 5],
 [5],
 [6],
 [7],
 [8],
 [8],
 [9, 10, 15],
 [11, 13, 17],
 [12, 16],
 [14],
 [18, 19, 20],
 [20, 21],
 [21, 23, 24, 26, 27],
 [22],
 [22, 25],
 [23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30]

Comment: example (1.3098258972167969-10) < -8.737972259521483 <(1.3098258972167969+10) is not true so [18,19,20] is not true and should be [18,19][19,20]

Comment: (1.3098258972167969-10) < -8.737972259521483 is not true

Comment: [ 
   ...
   [[4, 98.58261108398438], [5, 98.01058959960938]],
   [[5, 98.01058959960938], [6, -2.2177391052246094]],
    ...
]

You have 5 appearing twice. (Same with 8.)

Comment: yes it doesn't matter as long as there are no sublists, so if I had [4,5][5,6] it is fine, I cannot have [4,5][5] since [5] is a sublist of [4,5] the (1.3098258972167969-10) < -8.737972259521483 is not true but with ur code I get as output for the new example [18,19,20] and should be [18,19][19,20] instead

Comment: Okey, so the smallest and largest have to differ by less than 10? I understood it as each value must have at least one other value withing +/- 10.

Comment: The expected output is not a unique solution. Take the second to last list of lists. Here, [21, 26], [22, 25], [23, 24, 27] is also a solution (however we also get  [23, 24, 27, 28, 30] from the last list of lists, so  [23, 24, 27]  will be removed.